# How can I retrieve OpenLDAP server's STARTTLS certificate with Python's ssl library?

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, openldap, starttls

My goal is to retrieve the TLS certificates from online services and calculate the amount of seconds until they expire using Python. I have solved this for HTTPS:

```
import socket
import ssl
from datetime import datetime

from pytz as pytz
from asn1crypto.x509 import Certificate

def https_ttl(host, port):
    context = ssl.create_deafult_context()
    # we just want to check the certificate expiry date, we do not need to validate the chain of trust
    context.check_hostname = False
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

    with socket.create_connection((host, port)) as tcp_socket:
        with context.wrap_socket(tcp_socket, server_hostname=host) as ssl_socket:
            # getpeercert(binary_form=False) returns empty dict if verification is disabled
            cert = Certificate.load(ssl_socket.getpeercert(binary_form=True))

            return (cert.not_valid_after - datetime.now(pytz.utc)).total_seconds()
```

When I use `https_ttl()` to retrieve the certificate from an OpenLDAP server configured for STARTTLS, I receive this error message:

```
my_code.py:21: in https_ttl
    with self._context.wrap_socket(tcp_socket, server_hostname=host) as ssl_socket:
../../.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/ssl.py:500: in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
../../.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/ssl.py:1040: in _create
    self.do_handshake()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <ssl.SSLSocket [closed] fd=-1, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0>
block = False

    @_sslcopydoc
    def do_handshake(self, block=False):
        self._check_connected()
        timeout = self.gettimeout()
        try:
            if timeout == 0.0 and block:
                self.settimeout(None)
>           self._sslobj.do_handshake()
E           ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1131)

../../.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/ssl.py:1309: SSLEOFError
```

However, I can retrieve the certificate using `openssl` directly:

```
$ echo | openssl s_client -connect localhost:8389 -starttls ldap 2> /dev/null | sed -n '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/p'
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

How can I replicate the `openssl` invocation using Python's `ssl` library?

Comment: You have to send a STARTTLS command before switching to TLS.

Comment: Thank you! I posted an answer based on your feedback <3

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution based on @user207421's comment:

```
import socket
import ssl
from datetime import datetime

from pytz as pytz
from asn1crypto.x509 import Certificate

LDAP_START_TLS_SUCCESS = 0
LDAP_START_TLS_RESP_LENGTH = 14

def ldap_starttls_ttl(host, port):
    """Initiates STARTTLS handshake with OpenLDAP server and returns the certificate's time to live (TTL) in seconds."""
    context = ssl.create_deafult_context()
    # we just want to check the certificate expiry date, we do not need to validate the chain of trust
    context.check_hostname = False
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

    with socket.create_connection((host, port)) as tcp_socket:
        # send LDAP_START_TLS_OID (extracted from Wireshark)
        tcp_socket.send(
            b"\x30\x1d\x02\x01\x01\x77\x18\x80\x16\x31\x2e\x33\x2e\x36\x2e\x31"
            b"\x2e\x34\x2e\x31\x2e\x31\x34\x36\x36\x2e\x32\x30\x30\x33\x37"
        )

        extended_resp = tcp_socket.recv(LDAP_START_TLS_RESP_LENGTH)
        result_code = extended_resp[9]
        if result_code != LDAP_START_TLS_SUCCESS:
            raise ValueError(f'resultCode of LDAP_START_TLS_OID response is {result_code} instead of '
                             f'{LDAP_START_TLS_SUCCESS}')

        with context.wrap_socket(tcp_socket, server_hostname=host) as ssl_socket:
            # getpeercert(binary_form=False) returns empty dict if verification is disabled
            cert = Certificate.load(ssl_socket.getpeercert(binary_form=True))

            return (cert.not_valid_after - datetime.now(pytz.utc)).total_seconds()
```